# How to modify method which currently uses deprecated ComponentFactoryResolver and DomPortalOutlet

Tags: angular, angular-material

I upgraded the Angular version and I see that now ComponentFactoryResolver is depracated. I'm trying to figure out how to modify my code to another alternative.

This is my code:

```
export class SidenavService {
  private sidenavPortalOutlet!: PortalOutlet;
  private componentRef!: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private applicationRef: ApplicationRef) {}

  attachComponent(
    portal: ComponentPortal<any>,
    componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    injector: Injector
  ): ComponentRef<any> {
    this.sidenavPortalOutlet = new DomPortalOutlet(
      document.querySelector("#sidenav-portal-outlet") as Element,
      componentFactoryResolver,
      this.applicationRef,
      injector
    );
    this.componentRef = this.sidenavPortalOutlet.attach(portal);

    return this.componentRef;
  }

  detachComponent(): void {
    this.componentRef.destroy();
    this.sidenavPortalOutlet.detach();
  }
}
```

How could I modify that code removing the deprecated ComponentFactoryResolver?

Answer (score 3):

you can refactor your code in this way:

```
export class SidenavService {
  private componentRef!: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private applicationRef: ApplicationRef) {}

  attachComponent(): ComponentRef<any> {

    const componentRef = createComponent(Component, {
      environmentInjector: this.applicationRef.injector,
      hostElement: document.querySelector("#sidenav-portal-outlet") as 
       Element,
    })

    this.applicationRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

    return this.componentRef;
  }

 detachComponent(): void {
    this.componentRef.destroy();
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem now is that when "detachtComponent" is executed the div#sidenav-portal-outlet is removed from DOM, so next time I try to attach a new component it doesn't work because div#sidenav-portal-outlet doesn't exist